# Load data in a td of the same row where an option is marked

Tags: html, angular, typescript, mat-select

To make a demo of the problem I have a table where I show a list of details and several `mat-select` that when selecting an option the "size" of this marked option is loaded in the td.

[image: table]

The problem is that it does not load the "size" in the same row where an option is selected. How I can get this? The size is shown in the td but in order from top to bottom.

For example if there is no option marked and I select an option from row 3. The "size" of this option would be loaded in the first row and if I mark an option in any other row the data is loaded following the order of the rows.

I have the demo in stackblitz: [DemoStackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v7dvnd)

HTML

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Titles</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Detail</th>
    <th>Duration</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of dataDetails let i = index">
    <td>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-select [formControl]="dataCtrl" placeholder="Select" [compareWith]="compareItems" #singleSelect>
          <mat-option>
            <ngx-mat-select-search [formControl]="dataFilterCtrl"></ngx-mat-select-search>
          </mat-option>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let op of filteredData | async" [value]="op.id" (click)="onSelect(op)"
            [disabled]="op.condition===1">
            {{op.title}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
    <td>{{OptionSelected[i]?.size}}</td>
    <td>{{row.detail}}</td>
    <td>{{row.duration}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

TS

```
  dataTitles: any = DataTitles;
  dataDetails: any = DataDetails;
  dataCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  dataFilterCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  filteredData: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
  @ViewChild('singleSelect', { static: true }) singleSelect: MatSelect;

  _onDestroy = new Subject<void>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataCtrl.setValue(this.dataDetails[0]);
    this.filteredData.next(this.dataTitles.slice());
    this.dataFilterCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.filterData();
      });
  }
  compareItems(i1: any, i2: any) {
    return i1 && i2 && i1.key === i2.key;
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._onDestroy.next();
    this._onDestroy.complete();
  }
  OptionSelected: any = [];
  onSelect(option: any) {
    var objIndex = this.dataTitles.findIndex(x => x.id == option.id);
    if (this.dataTitles[objIndex].title !== 'None') {
      this.dataTitles[objIndex].condition = 1;
    }
    if (this.OptionSelected.length === 0) {
      this.OptionSelected.push({ id: option.id, size: option.size });
    } else {
      let check = this.OptionSelected.map((item: any) => item.id).includes(
        option.id
      );
      if (check === false) {
        this.OptionSelected.push({ id: option.id, size: option.size });
      }
    }
    console.log(this.OptionSelected);
  }
  filterData() {
    if (!this.dataTitles) {
      return;
    }
    let search = this.dataFilterCtrl.value;
    if (!search) {
      this.filteredData.next(this.dataTitles.slice());
      return;
    } else {
      search = search.toLowerCase();
    }
    this.filteredData.next(
      this.dataTitles.filter(
        (x: any) => x.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1
      )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue**

You´r pushing the current selected value into the `OptionSelected` during the call of
`onSelect`. This causes the mismatch of selected row data and which row actualy shows the data.

Pseudo code example:

```
Select TitleA in Row 4
Push new Data into OptionSelected
OptionSelected[0]?.size displays data in the first row
```

---

**Solution**

You are already tracking the value of the current selected value with the template variable `#singleSelect` over here:

```
<mat-select ... #singleSelect>
```

The `<mat-select>` component has a value input.

```
@Input()
value: any Value of the select control.
```

So you can display the current value by simply using the template ref:

```
<td>{{singleSelect.value}}</td>
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbdj3d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)